# Images in a list view produces out of memory

Tags: android, android-listview, out-of-memory, android-bitmap

I want to display a thumbnail size image and a text as a list view item. But all the images coming from the server are of a larger size. This is leading to an out of memory error. I am using network Image view to display the images. Will the memory contain the large sized image or the re-sized image? Can I avoid these errors if i use picasso?

Comment: You can decode your images using `BitmapFactory.Options` and generate scaled bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to down sample large images

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8; 
Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
```

Also take a look at [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

you should to use Glide Lib,that is recommend by google. it avoid error from out of memory too.

**suggest this :** 
[Introduction to Glide, Image Loader Library for Android, recommended by Google](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)

Comment: I have used Glide Lib it works fine but still got the same issue "Out of memory" even though I am setting Thumbnail in Image View

Comment: I also use Glide in ListView and get OOM exception.

Answer (score 0):

Scale the bitmap with lower size and also add **largeHeap** property under **application** tag in manifest

```
    android:largeHeap="true"
```